# In Titan graph Db difference UniquenessConsistence.LOCK vs UniquenessConsistence.NO_LOCK

Tags: graph-databases, titan

I am using titan for my app.
What does `UniquenessConsistence.LOCK` mean?. Does it mean Isolation level Serializable?

What is the performance difference between `UniquenessConsistence.LOCK` and `UniquenessConsistence.NO_LOCK`?

I cannot seem to find it anywhere in Titan Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the Titan [docs](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview#uniqueness-consistency):

> When the underlying storage backend supports transactional isolation,
>   titan will delegate consistency checks and locks to the storage
>   backend. To avoid such inconsistencies on eventually consistent
>   backends, Titan can acquire locks and will do so by default. Acquiring
>   locks, however, can be very expensive. In cases where concurrent
>   modifications can be excluded or blind overwrites are acceptable one
>   may alter this default behavior.

This question was also addressed in the Aurelius Graphs mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/0_39YzRas0U)